# How to fetch microsoft account's photo after signing in in android

Tags: android, kotlin, get, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to fetch user's profile photo after signing in in my app but I don't know how to do this I googled for this problem but I didn't find any efficient solution

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you're using the graph API, as you tagged, [then they already have an endpoint for the photo](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer?request=me%2Fphoto%2F%24value&method=GET&version=v1.0&GraphUrl=https://graph.microsoft.com):

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/photo/$value
```

You can find this in the [Graph explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer)

Comment: Yes, I tried to get the photo using coil, but it didn't success, the tutorial says that I must use microsoft graph API but the API I know is for signing in and returns JSON object so I don't know how to use microsoft graph API to fetch a photo

Comment: How to use it in kotlin ?